# K-nearest neighbours in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, beginner, matlab, clustering

I implemented K-Nearest Neighbours algorithm, but my experience using MATLAB is lacking. I need you to check the small portion of code and tell me what can be improved or modified.  I hope it is a correct implementation of the algorithm.

```
function test_data = knn(test_data, tr_data,k)

numoftestdata = size(test_data,1);
numoftrainingdata = size(tr_data,1);


for sample=1:numoftestdata

   %Step 1: Computing euclidean distance for each testdata
   R = repmat(test_data(sample,:),numoftrainingdata,1) ;
   euclideandistance  = (R(:,1) - tr_data(:,1)).^2;

   %Step 2: compute k nearest neighbors and store them in an array
    [dist position] = sort(euclideandistance,'ascend');
    knearestneighbors=position(1:k);
    knearestdistances=dist(1:k);


    % Step 3 : Voting 
    for i=1:k
        A(i) = tr_data(knearestneighbors(i),2);  
    end

    M = mode(A);

    if (M~=1)
        test_data(sample,2) = mode(A);
    else 
        test_data(sample,2) = tr_data(knearestneighbors(1),2);
    end
end
```

To test it you can use :

- test_data = [6,0; 2,0; 5,0]
- tr_data = [1,1;0,2;3,2; 4,4; 5,3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use consistent indentation.
- You switch from extremely verbose all lower case variable names like `numoftrainingdata` to single letter capitalized variable names like `A`. Make your variable names descriptive and no longer than necessary, and be consistent.
- Use consistent white space between operators.
- `knn()` doesn't need the second column of `test_data`, and the calling function doesn't need the first column of `test_data`.

  Rather than calling the function like this:

  ```
  test_data = knn(test_data,tr_data,k);
  ```

  Call it like this:

  ```
  test_data(:,2) = knn(test_data(1,:),tr_data,k);
  ```
- Do you want to handle certain error conditions like `0 >= k` or `k > size(tr_data,1)`?
- Rather than squaring the distance, you can use `abs()`.
- Remove the ascend parameter from `sort()`, that is the default mode.
- `knearestdistances` is unused.
- You call `mode()` a second time rather than using `M`.

Simplify:

```
[dist position] = sort(euclideandistance,'ascend');
knearestneighbors = position(1:k);
knearestdistances = dist(1:k);
for i=1:k
    A(i) = tr_data(knearestneighbors(i),2);
end
M = mode(A);
if (M~=1)
    test_data(sample,2) = mode(A);
else 
    test_data(sample,2) = tr_data(knearestneighbors(1),2);
end
```

to

```
[~,position] = sort(euclideandistance);
A = tr_data(position(1:k),2);
M = mode(A);
if (M~=1)
    test_data(sample,2) = M;
else
    test_data(sample,2) = tr_data(position(1),2);
end
```

After applying the above suggestions and vectorizing the function you could write it as:

```
function out_data = knn(test_data,tr_data,k)
    test_data_n = size(test_data,1);
    tr_data_n = size(tr_data,1);

    % absolute distance between all test and training data
    dist = abs(repmat(test_data,1,tr_data_n) - repmat(tr_data(:,1)',test_data_n,1));

    % indicies of nearest neighbors
    [~,nearest] = sort(dist,2);
    % k nearest
    nearest = nearest(:,1:k);

    % mode of k nearest
    val = reshape(tr_data(nearest,2),[],k);
    out_data = mode(val,2);
    % if mode is 1, output nearest instead
    out_data(out_data==1) = val(out_data==1,1);
end
```

### Edit

Regarding correctness, i'm not sure why you check to see if the mode is 1. There is nothing unique about a mode of 1 in general.

Comment: I made a mistake, If the frequency of the mode is One , that means all values of `val` are unique, we choose the nearest.

Comment: `    [M,F] = mode(knntrdata);
    if (F~=1)
        test_data(sample,2) = M;
    else
        test_data(sample,2) = tr_data(position(1),2);
    end`

Comment: is it necessary to vectorize the function ?

Comment: @ALJIMohamed Yes that code looks correct to check if all the values are unique. Vectorization is only necessary if your code is too verbose or slow. The only part of your code that needs to be vectorized is the assignment of `A`, because it is too verbose. I vectorized the rest as an example.